# How to add a Marker/Pin on an ImageView Android?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-canvas, marker

I would like to ask on how to implement or add a marker on an imageView.
I rendered an SVG using svglib and used a customImageView so that I can zoom and pan around the image.

here is my code on how i used my customImageView

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SVG svg;
        switch (mNum) {

        case 1:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t1);
            break;
        case 2:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t2);
            break;
        case 3:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t3);
            break;
        case 4:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t4);
            break;
        default:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),
                    R.raw.android);

        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView = (GestureImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setStrict(false);
        imageView.setStartingScale(lastScale);
        // if(lastXPosition!=0 && lastYPosition!=0)
        imageView.setStartingPosition(lastXPosition, lastYPosition);
        // Log.i("tag",
        // "lastXPosition" + lastXPosition);
        // Log.i("tag",
        // "lastYPosition" + lastYPosition);
        // Log.i("tag",
        // "lastScale" + lastScale);
        // imageView.setRotation(45);
        // imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
            imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        ((TextView) tv).setText("Floor number: " + mNum);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
        // android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
        // imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        // ((GestureImageView)imageView).setScale(x);
        return v;
    }
```

Now I would like to add a pin just like the image below...

[image: My problem]
<sub>(source: [modality.com](http://www.modality.com/images/appimages/130/screens/645/large.png))</sub>

But my problem is that when I pan around the marker I added is not bonded with the image SVG thus left behind at a certain position when panning...

Here's my code...
NOTE: Not yet final... I'm still looking for a way to get this working and I am using a zoomed in imageview as a map...

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (layout) {
        if (drawable != null && !isRecycled()) {
            canvas.save();

            float adjustedScale = scale * scaleAdjust;

            canvas.translate(x, y);

            if (rotation != 0.0f) {
                canvas.rotate(rotation);
            }

            if (adjustedScale != 1.0f) {
                canvas.scale(adjustedScale, adjustedScale);
            }

            drawable.draw(canvas);

            canvas.restore();
        }

        if (drawLock.availablePermits() <= 0) {
            drawLock.release();
        }
    }

    // ---add the marker---
    Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.search_marker_icon);
    canvas.drawBitmap(marker, 40, 40, null);
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(60, 60, 5, mPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Thanks.... I'm new to android  :) hope you can help me....

[image: My problem]

Comment: not yet... im currently working on some parts of my program.... i'll post the answer when i'll find the solution

Comment: @dicenice have you got the solution, i have same problem(i wana implement same like this)

Comment: @dicenice how did you manage to add `infoWindow` to this marker?

Comment: Can you send sample project same like this because I also want to add pinmark images to  a floor plan ..Please help me .

Comment: @dicenice I want your help bro. I exactly need same kind of features but when I am zooming my image marker position got changed. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 drawable.draw(canvas);

// ---add the marker---
Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.search_marker_icon);
canvas.drawBitmap(marker, 40, 40, null);
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawCircle(60, 60, 5, mPaint);


        canvas.restore();
    }

    if (drawLock.availablePermits() <= 0) {
        drawLock.release();
    }
}
 super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

You need to do this before canvas.restore..... :D got this solution last year...... thnx for the help guys.... my app is almost done :)

Comment: It'll be a great help if you can post some more codes related to this. Especially the GestureImageView class.

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue for a long time. So please help.

Comment: bro can you help this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014212/how-to-place-pin-mark-image-over-an-image-using-ontouchlistener

Answer (score 6):

This is a nice library for displaying images, which supports zooming/panning and adding pins over the image
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: How can i add pins to the SubsamplingScaleImageView object?

Comment: Check out the PinView example he provides. This is one of the best libraries I found, thanks @Singed for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

An implementation of an HTML map like element in an Android View:

- Supports images as drawable or bitmap in layout
- Allows for a list of area tags in xml
- Enables use of cut and paste HTML area tags to a resource xml  (ie, the ability to take an HTML map - and image and use it with minimal editing)
- Supports panning if the image is larger than the device screen
- Supports pinch-zoom
- Supports callbacks when an area is tapped.
- Supports showing annotations as bubble text and provide callback if the bubble is tapped

try this link you will find your solution https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap