# how to add a pin marker on image view in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-view, viewgroup

i am working on a project where i need to add pins on image view as shown in below image.
how could we do this.

[image: example image]

i successfully created a zoomable image view using

**TouchImageview.java**

```
 class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);       


}

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);



            Log.e("Deepak", "X" + event.getRawX());

            Log.e("Deepak", "Y" + event.getRawY());



            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());



            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                        if (scaleWidth < width) {
                            deltaX = 0;
                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                        } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                            deltaY = 0;
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);
                        } else {
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) { 
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x)
{

    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float)Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX =  (float)width / (float)bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float)height / (float)bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float)height - (scale * (float)bmHeight) ;
    redundantXSpace = (float)width - (scale * (float)bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

}
```

now i need to add markers on it.
any help for it.

Comment: i searched and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679189/how-to-add-a-marker-pin-on-an-imageview-android but didn't get solution

Comment: Well can you draw them on the image you got and save it as new Bitmap?

Comment: @vodich ok but how to add click event to markers(i tried for it. but after creating single Bitmap there is problem in click event).

Comment: @CommonsWare do you know how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found my answer here https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap

An implementation of an HTML map like element in an Android View:

- Supports images as drawable or bitmap in layout
- Allows for a list of area tags in xml
- Enables use of cut and paste HTML area tags to a resource xml  (ie, the ability to take an HTML map - and image and use it with minimal editing)
- Supports panning if the image is larger than the device screen
- Supports pinch-zoom
- Supports callbacks when an area is tapped.
- Supports showing annotations as bubble text and provide callback if the bubble is tapped

Answer (score 5):

I have used AndroidImageMap but i don't like how it zooms the image, and you don't have facilities to add custom views as clickable areas.

Checkout this example project https://github.com/jzafrilla/AndroidImageHostpot I have used https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/ to get Zoom and Pan functionality.

Hope this helps...(to me, absolutely yes)

Comment: I managed to implement this functionality with PhotoView. Your code helped me, thanks.
However, your approach requires PhotoView library modifications, which is not really necessary: the better solution is to set the onMatrixChangeListener to the photoView and put the code for updating coordinates there.

Also, this is a library that looks promising. It supports zooming/panning and adding pins over the image
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view