# Adding markers on an image

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image in a custom imageview, which is a layout of a building. I need to add buttons(or markers like in google maps) in few places on the image with a longclick or drag and drop a button from the top of the screen. How the button(or marker) comes doesnt matter, but the main problem is im unable to get it on top of an image. I want it just like a marker on google map, should be able to perform onclick and onlongclick operations. Should even be able to delete it. After that i need to save my image with those buttons i added in order to load it the next time my app launches, just like my saved places in google maps.

Can anyone please suggest me a best way to do it. I am new to android and I am sorry if the same question has already been asked, I would appreciate if u can give me a link to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987975/how-to-add-a-pin-marker-on-image-view-in-android

Comment: Hi Anukool, im sorry, but the link didn't help me. I want to add a child to the image on a click event, which i suppose, will be a button. Can this be done in any way. It would be helpful if anyone can suggest me how to add a button as a child to an image. Thanks in advance.