# Is there a way to add marker on an ImageView

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, smcalloutview

I want to replicate [this](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview) great iOS library (SMCalloutView) on Android?

In it's example, a marker (pin on iOS) is created and added on a scrollable, zoomable imageView. And when the marker is clicked, an `infoWindow` (callout view on iOS) is shown. How do I achieve this behaviour? Is there a similar library to this? Should I draw the marker and show info window manually? Is there at least any way to use `Marker` and it's `infoWindow` on an `ImageView`.

[image: SMCalloutView example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best choice I could find is this [library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/) It has a pin sample you could use.

Add pin as a bitmap, override add an `OnPinClickListener` interface (see samples for where to invoke the `onPinClick` method).

```
if (pinRect.contains((int)touchCoord.x, (int)touchCoord.y)) {
    onPinClickListener.onPinClicked(i);
}
```

I still have no answer for info window.

Comment: You should be able to implement the info window as another overlay graphic, perhaps using a 9 patch background.

Comment: Hey, can either osri or Dave please provide an implementation example of OnPinCickListener showing how to override ? I am in search of this problem too

Comment: I am looking at the piniew example in the library, but would like a more detailed example of implementing an onPinClick

Answer (score 0):

sorry, there is no native `View` with this "pinning" feature as I know, but you might check [this library](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap) and maybe [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987975/how-to-add-a-pin-marker-on-image-view-in-android)

for popup you might use default Android `Popup` or QuickAction lib (one of two) from [here](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt)

Comment: Is there any similar library that allows to put the pins as views instead? This library put a static image that can't even be changed.