# android how to add marker on image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I need to add marker on specific pixel on image how can i do it any ideas and
I need to make an action when clicked on the image i read this article but i didn't know How to start with it

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SVG svg;
        switch (mNum) {

        case 1:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t1);
            break;
        case 2:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t2);
            break;
        case 3:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t3);
            break;
        case 4:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.t4);
            break;
        default:
            svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),
                    R.raw.android);

        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView = (GestureImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setStrict(false);
        imageView.setStartingScale(lastScale);
        // if(lastXPosition!=0 && lastYPosition!=0)
        imageView.setStartingPosition(lastXPosition, lastYPosition);
        // Log.i("tag",
        // "lastXPosition" + lastXPosition);
        // Log.i("tag",
        // "lastYPosition" + lastYPosition);
        // Log.i("tag",
        // "lastScale" + lastScale);
        // imageView.setRotation(45);
        // imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
            imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        ((TextView) tv).setText("Floor number: " + mNum);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
        // android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
        // imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        // ((GestureImageView)imageView).setScale(x);
        return v;
    }
```

[this is what i need exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210767/1093822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions and they depend on your needs

1. You should create your own class which extends ImageView or whichever widget are you using to hold your image and override onDraw and there draw your pixel wherever you want.
2. If your needs are on more permanent pixel location. You should create bitmap from your image and then draw pixel and after that assign your bitmap to whichever widget do you want.

If you need to move your marker I would go with first suggestion, and in opposite case with second

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.